# Why should I use web services between android app and MySQL database(remote)?

Tags: java, android, web-services, sqlite, rest

I came across suggestions of using web services between android app and both. But here are my concerns

Cons:
1) More development time of web services
2) Securing it. 
3) Performace - Won't the web services become an additional layer in between and consume some time in processing data and requests?

Pros:
Having web services will help building iOS version; but when iOS is made to talk to DB directly, this is solved. It doesn't make any difference as database is going to get same number of DB calls. This is not a big pros.
Lets say Android app from 100 users directly makes 100 calls to DB, then 100 iOS users make 100 calls, then the same 200 calls will be made from web services to DB. So What is the point?

1) Why should I use web services between android app and MySQL database.
2) Lets say if I plan to build web services, I don't want normal public to access my database using webservices(through URLs). How to secure it? There is no username and password thing in my app. I want only my app installers to see (get) some data from web services. If I use some kinda key in my app, Can't people decode android apk and see the keys? Please answer both the questions as well.

Comment: How do you plan to connect from your Android to a mysql db without a web service???

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question. Basically, this is a broad topic, and the strong recommendation is to use web services to mainly to sanitize the data and perform other server side operations rather than rely on the mobile device to handle complex queries

Comment: @rakeshkashyap That is my next question. Isn't there a way to connect a remote DB to android app straight away? Sync Adapter or Content Provider (I am a newbie, so not sure if those would help me or not).

Comment: @cricket_007 My query is select 10 results from table where countryName='<userProvidedValue>'. If my app involves more DB transactions like FB (more likes, comments etc.) then I would have chosen web services. But my point is just a select query. So little bit worried. 
Could you answer about question number 2) (securing web servers).

Comment: you can use sqlite which is a in built DB for android, if you just need to do a query as above

Comment: @rakeshkashyap  But How to sync data from my remote DB to sqlite DB?

Comment: Basics of connecting to a DB. You need a driver specific to the DB and platform. To connect to a DB like mysql or oracle, driver for Android is not available, and also it does not make any sense to make such driver due to system constraints.. Web service is the only feasible option here

Comment: Honestly, it requires a lot of work is required to truly secure anything. And you'd have to store any API or database password in the app in either scenario you had, so you should look at how easy it is to decompile a signed APK file if you really that concerned about it

Comment: And if you really care about syncing, try Firebase. It's free

Comment: I agree with @cricket_007.. But remember its web service to firebase that makes this possible.. this is internally handled by google's API

Comment: You can use `JDBC drivers` to directly connect to database (what I've tried to achieve) but some parts of these `APIs` aren't supported in `API < 19` and as the Mobile device usually has less bandwidth and CPU power than a computer it's better to use a `web service`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about 
1. Scale - Tomorrow if you change the schema or db ..It will be much easier to change the REST APIs than changing your logic all over everywhere
2. Web service are closer to standards
3. Open up your architecture for different clients like web app or hybrid apps

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you answer my question (2) please?

Comment: for securing a web API you can explore options of using a JWT

Comment: @rakeshkashyap Thx. I went thru JWT. But it says login authentication, in my case, my requirement is, only my android app installed on phones should contact my web services, and any1 who got the URL of my webservices should fail to get data. So there is no username and pwd here. How can I do this? Please help me. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use web service from ANDROID to your DATABASE?

```
1.) Database security  purpose.
2.) Easy to communicate between android to database(Bridge).
3.) Best way of handling text, blob etc.
```

Comment: I understand the necessity of web services and started using it. I am using Jersey, but I am struck how to make it talk to mysql database. I know I have to use mysql driver, but how about maintain connections, open/closing connections etc. Please guide me. Thanks.